# Tikxml avoiding spaces at the begining of the text content

Tags: android, annotations, tikxml

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testXml attribute="attribute">    content   </testXml>
```

My pojo class

```
@Xml(name = "testXml")
data class TestXml (
    @Attribute
    val attribute: String,
    @TextContent
    val content: String
)
```

When convert above xml to pojo, I am not getting spaces which are at the begining of the text content `content`.

But I am able to get spaces which are at the end of the text content `content`

Comment: XML trims by default, use `xml:space="preserve"` in the root tag. Not sure if tikxml supports it though.

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me how to map ````xml:space="preserve"```` to POJO class above?